# Arduino Yun - Problem with bridge and client

Tags: arduino-yun, web-server

I'm using this simple code

```
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <YunServer.h>
#include <YunClient.h>

YunServer server;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Bridge.begin();
  server.listenOnLocalhost();
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  YunClient client = server.accept();
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("client");
    process(client);
    client.stop();
   } else {
     Serial.println("no client");
   }
   delay(50); 
}

void process(YunClient client) {
  String command = client.readStringUntil('/');
  Serial.println(command);
  if (command == "turnLeft") {
    Serial.println("Gira a sinistra");
  }
  if (command == "turnRight") {
    Serial.println("Gira a destra");
  }
  if (command == "goTo") {
    String value = client.readStringUntil('/goTo/');
    Serial.println(value);
  }
}
```

but it seems to have problem with bridge (or server, or client, i cannot understand) because it only write "no client" on the serial.

I can not understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to answer your question. Your problem is on line

```
if (client)
```

Change it to

```
if(client.connected())
```

which actually returns true when client is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are wanting the print output to show up on the Serial Monitor but you have connected the Arduino IDE to the Yun via the WiFi port on your network. If this is the case, then change all refs of Serial.print to Console.print
This will direct the ASCII text to the Serial Monitor.